# What will happen to a handler if the looper it is handling is quit?

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a thread handler which handles the looper of a "worker" thread. At some point in my Activity's lifecycle, I am calling "quit" method on the worker thread which releases its current looper. Then what will happen to the (worker) thread handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once you call quit on looper, it will discard all the messages in que and will not take further messages.